# Append Single quotes in Query Postgres Function?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1, concatenation

I am trying to append single quote in query in postgres function but result in error please have a look on my postgres function,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE function test() returns my_type as $$
    declare rd varchar := '56';
    declare personphone varchar := 'Philip Dannes';
    declare result my_type;
    declare SQL VARCHAR(300):=null; 
        BEGIN        
        -- Mandatory / Static part of the Query here
        SQL = 'select pt.id from product_template pt inner join product_product pp on pt.id=pp.id where  ';

        IF rd IS NOT NULL        
            then        
                 SQL =  SQL || 'pp.radio_phone = '|| rd;
        else   
   SQL =  SQL || 'pp.radio_phone = '|| rd;
        end if;       

        IF personphone IS NOT NULL        
            then      
                SQL = SQL || ' and pp.person_phone = '|| personphone;   
            else
  SQL = SQL || ' and pp.person_phone = '|| personphone;    
        end if;

        SQL = SQL || ';';    

        EXECUTE SQL;         
return result;        
    END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

when i execute it it gives me error on "Philip Daves" and return query after appending as,

```
Select pt.id from product_template pt inner join product_product pp on pt.id=pp.id where 
pp.radio_phone = 56 and  pp.person_phone = Philip Dave
```

I know error is because 56 and Philip Dave is not in single quote when i execute function return query with single quote it works fine.

How would i append Single quote in this query ??

I tried in this way like,

```
SQL = SQL || ' and pp.person_phone = '|| '' || personphone;
```

But i function return the same query

Hopes for your suggestion

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to rewrite this rather heavily.

First, use `quote_ident` and `quote_literal` instead of manual quoting.

Better, use `format()` with the `%I` and `%L` specifiers for identifiers and literals if you're on a newer PostgreSQL version.

Also, try to avoid building strings iteratively like that. Build with an expression with `CASE`s where possible

There's no need for any `varchar(300)` business. Just use `text`.

Your `ELSE` clauses seem to contain the same thing as your `IF ... THEN`. I've removed them.

Try using `RETURN QUERY EXECUTE` or, if you're getting just one value, `EXECUTE ... INTO`.

```
DECLARE
    radiophone_clause text = '';
    personphone_clause text = '';
BEGIN        
    IF rd IS NOT NULL then
        radiophone_clause = 'and pp.radio_phone = '|| quote_literal(rd);
    END IF;

    IF personphone IS NOT NULL then      
        personphone_clause = ' and pp.person_phone = '|| quote_literal(personphone);
    END IF;

    RETURN QUERY EXECUTE format('select pt.id from product_template pt inner join product_product pp on pt.id=pp.id where true %s %s', radiophone_clause, personphone_clause);
END;
```

See [the manual for info on `quote_ident` and `quote_literal`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html).

Comment: can i have any example for appending quotes as you mentioned ?